# Is it possible to clear Automator logs?

Tags: macos, automator

How do I clear Automator logs?

Comment: Do you mean the logs shown inside the automator app? Or logs generated by workflows or apps you created using the automator app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to ~/Library/Logs/ find the log file, and delete it. Or, if there isn't a log file for Automator there, go to /Library/Logs and find the file there.